# How can I get the setup for updated Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I want to reset my PC,so all my installed softwares will vanish after resetting.I have the setup of older version of android studio but I updated it to newest version few days back.I can use the newest version of Android studio but I don't have its setup.How can I get the setup of newest version without needing to downloading anything so that I can use it after I reset my PC?

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry, just copy your android-studio folder and Android Folder and copy it to a safe drive then reset your pc ...

Comment: Now that I have reset my PC,should I use the old setup or do something else?